# new excel spreadsheet library for excel generate demo for PHP codigniter

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, spreadsheet

i am using https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet this library. If we include this library we getting error related to class. We facing issue of spreadsheet class not found.

how to generate excel using spreadsheet library. if any example it is help full for me.

Comment: We're here to help you sort out potential errors/issues you might run into, but for us to be able to do that, you need to post the relevant code and explain the error in detail. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that was recommended to you when you registered.

Comment: I used `PHPExcel` library in an old project

Comment: @AnkitJindal - That library hasn't been updated since 2015, it was deprecated back in 2017 and is now completely dead. PHPSpreadsheet is the the project that came after and that should be used instead.

Comment: @bharat-kadachha Please post the actual error received. In addition, show us some source code of how you're using the library.

Comment: @bharat-kadachha Try using 
`$filename = "sample.csv";
$output = fopen($filename, 'w'); 
fputcsv($output, $data, $delimiter);
fclose($output);`

Comment: Live Server spreadsheet not found   Problem solve just local project vendor folder live directory paste (project home dircetory) spreadsheet class not found problem solve

Answer (score 0):

Just go through https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation once for installation.Earlier i too faced the issue but i can use it on both localhost and liveserver.
Here is the sample code...

```
<?php 
        $host = 'hostaddress';
        $user = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $database = 'db';

        $conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect to database" . mysqli_connect_errno();
        }

        $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM restaurent_feedback ");
        $output = '';
        $i = 1;
        if($query1->num_rows > 0){
            $output = '<table border=1>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Slno</th>
                          <th>Restaurent_Name </th>
                          <th>Estimation_Name</th>
                          <th>Comment</th>
                          <th>Commented_By</th>
                          <th>Commented_on</th>
                        </tr>
            ';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
            $output .= '<tr>
                            <td>'.$i.'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['rest_name'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['est_name'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['comment'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['created_by'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['created_on'].'</td>
                </tr>';
                $i++;
        }
        $output .= "</table>";
    }
    require "vendor/autoload.php";
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
    $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Html();
    $spreadsheet = $reader->loadFromString($output);
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.md-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"exporttoexcel.xls\"");
    $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');
    $writer->save("php://output"); 
    ?>
```

[here is the output which i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4bcL.png)